# How can I merge two MySQL tables?

Tags: sql, mysql, merge

How can I merge two MySQL tables that have the same structure?

The primary keys of the two tables will clash, so I have take that into account.

Comment: When you say that the PKs might clash, do you mean that there might be duplicate rows and you don't want them copied, or that you need to assign a new PK to one of them because they're really different rows despite having the same PK? (yet another reason to use natural primary keys)

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You can also try:

```
INSERT IGNORE
  INTO table_1 
SELECT *
  FROM table_2
     ;
```

which allows those rows in table_1 to supersede those in table_2 that have a matching primary key, while still inserting rows with new primary keys.

Alternatively,

```
REPLACE
   INTO table_1
 SELECT *
   FROM table_2
      ;
```

will update those rows already in table_1 with the corresponding row from table_2, while inserting rows with new primary keys.

Comment: Actually, it will [REPLACE](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/replace-into-think-twice) existing rows (delete + insert), not update.

Comment: what about if there is any foreign key used for table 2????? How you will updated that?

Answer (score 41):

It depends on the semantic of the primary key. If it's just autoincrement, then use something like:

```
insert into table1 (all columns except pk)
select all_columns_except_pk 
from table2;
```

If PK means something, you need to find a way to determine which record should have priority. You could create a select query to find duplicates first (see [answer by cpitis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725556/how-can-i-merge-two-mysql-tables/725571#725571)). Then eliminate the ones you don't want to keep and use the above insert to add records that remain.

Answer (score 22):

```
INSERT
INTO    first_table f
SELECT  *
FROM    second_table s
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE
        s.column1 = DO_WHAT_EVER_MUST_BE_DONE_ON_KEY_CLASH(f.column1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the good idea. The above cmd gives me a syntax error though. But this works for me:
INSERT
INTO    first_table
SELECT  *
FROM    second_table
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
second_table.column1 = DO_WHAT_EVER_MUST_BE_DONE_ON_KEY_CLASH(first_table.column1)

Comment: Just like @Tapper, I could not get to assign an Alias to the first table. I would get `Syntax error, unexpected IDENT_QUOTED` - through MySQL Workbench anyways.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what command you would enter on the last line?  I would like the ID to increment up from the highest existing ID in the table

Answer (score 16):

If you need to do it manually, one time:

First, merge in a temporary table, with something like:

```
create table MERGED as select * from table 1 UNION select * from table 2
```

Then, identify the primary key constraints with something like

```
SELECT COUNT(*), PK from MERGED GROUP BY PK HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Where PK is the primary key field...

Solve the duplicates.

Rename the table.

[edited - removed brackets in the UNION query, which was causing the error in the comment below]

Comment: when I try this I receieved this error, "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION select * from actor)' at line ", why is that?

Answer (score 7):

Not as complicated as it sounds....
Just leave the duplicate primary key out of your query....
this works for me !

```
INSERT INTO
  Content(
    `status`,
    content_category,
    content_type,
    content_id,
    user_id,
    title,
    description,
    content_file,
    content_url,
    tags,
    create_date,
    edit_date,
    runs
  )
SELECT `status`,
  content_category,
  content_type,
  content_id,
  user_id,
  title,
  description,
  content_file,
  content_url,
  tags,
  create_date,
  edit_date,
  runs
FROM
  Content_Images
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a script to update the FK's for you.. check out this blog: http://www.multunus.com/blog/2011/03/script-to-merge-two-identical-mysql-databases/

They have a clever script to use the information_schema tables to get the "id" columns:

```
SET @db:='id_new'; 

select @max_id:=max(AUTO_INCREMENT) from information_schema.tables;

select concat('update ',table_name,' set ', column_name,' = ',column_name,'+',@max_id,' ; ') from information_schema.columns where table_schema=@db and column_name like '%id' into outfile 'update_ids.sql';
 
use id_new
source update_ids.sql;
```