# DELETING doubled users (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1093

I have two tables. There are users informations from two sites:
`p_users`
`p_users2`
There are 3726 users in first and 13717 in second.
Some users in `p_users2` are in `p_users`. I want merge this two tables to the one big table - but rows with same usernames can't be doubled.

How can I do this? I tried something like this:

```
DELETE FROM p_users2 WHERE user_id IN 
(
select p.user_id from p_users p
join p_users2 p2 on p.username=p2.username
)
```

After that I should receive a table with unique usernames, which I want to export and import to the first one. But when I execute my query I got error:

> SQL Error (1093): You can't specify target table 'p_users2' for update in FROM clause. (MYSQL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
DELETE p2 FROM p_pusers2 AS P2
INNER JOIN p_users p1
ON p1.username=p2.username
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a new table where the username is unique, then do an Insert Ignore... see:

[How can I merge two MySQL tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725556/how-can-i-merge-two-mysql-tables)

Answer (score 1):

Do them as two separate statements.  First delete the duplicates with:

```
DELETE FROM p_users2 WHERE user_id IN 
(select p.user_id from p_users p)
```

Then use the [INSERT with SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) statement:

```
INSERT INTO P_USERS (FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3) SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3 FROM P_USERS2
```

Answer (score 0):

only insert users from the second table where there is no matching student in the first table

```
INSERT INTO p_users
SELECT * FROM p_users2 p2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM p_users p1
  WHERE p1.id = p2.id
)
```