# MySQL | You can't specify target table 'a' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1093

```
DELETE FROM table_a WHERE id IN(
    SELECT table_a.id AS id FROM table_a, table_b 
    WHERE table_a.object_id = 1 AND table_a.code = 'code' 
        AND table_a.code = table_b.code 
        AND table_b.id = table_a.b_id 
        AND table_b.table = 'testTable')
```

This is a (somewhat simplified) query I want MySQL to execute. I read on other pages of stackoverflow that this wasn't supported and that it's solvable by using JOINS. How could this be 'transcribed' to a query using JOINS? I find it hard to do so, because I've never tried creating DELETE queries with more than one table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [DELETING doubled users (MySQL)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669165/deleting-doubled-users-mysql)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't delete from a table and reference the same table in a subquery — just a limitation of MySQL. Something like the following should work:

```
DELETE FROM table_a 
USING table_a
INNER JOIN table_b
    ON table_a.code = table_b.code
    AND table_b.id = table_a.b_id
    AND table_b.table = 'testTable'
WHERE table_a.object_id = 1 
    AND table_a.code = 'code'
```

The important part is `USING`. If you just join the two tables, you'll delete records from both. `USING` tells MySQL to use these tables for processing, but only delete from the tables in the `FROM` clause.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

Answer (score 4):

This is a common MySQL issue, use a temporary table between the select and update/delete:

```
DELETE FROM table_a WHERE id IN 
   (select id from 
       (SELECT table_a.id AS id FROM table_a, table_b 
        WHERE table_a.object_id = 1 
        AND table_a.code = 'code' 
        AND table_a.code = table_b.code 
        AND table_b.id = table_a.b_id 
        AND table_b.table = 'testTable')
    ) tempTable
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two (slightly different) syntaxes for deleting from mutliple tables. Here's the one without `USING`:

```
DELETE a
FROM 
      table_a AS a 
  INNER JOIN 
      table_b AS b
    ON  b.code = a.code
    AND b.id   = a.b_id   
WHERE 
      a.object_id = 1 
  AND a.code = 'code' 
  AND b.`table` = 'testTable'   --- Do you actually have a column named "table"?
```

Answer (score 0):

My Way ... If you could use that!

```
DELETE FROM table_a WHERE id IN(SELECT id FROM(SELECT id FROM table_a WHERE userid=99 GROUP BY mobile HAVING COUNT(mobile) > 1) as t2)
```