# #1093 - You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote this delete for an application with mysql db and it doesn't work, I already search for answers but I cant find any kind error, someone can help me with a tip about this?
thanks

> 1093 - You can't specify target table 'md1_acessos' for update in FROM clause

```
DELETE FROM md1_acessos
WHERE ID_USUARIO = 10
AND ID_UNIDADE not in ( 
    SELECT ID_UNIDADE 
    FROM md1_acessos
    WHERE ID_EMPRESA = 1
    AND ID_USUARIO = 1
    AND ID_MODULO IN (1,2,6)
);
```

Comment: See this for a workaround. http://verysimple.com/2011/03/30/mysql-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause/

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285143/mysql-you-cant-specify-target-table-a-for-update-in-from-clause

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM md1_acessos
WHERE ID_USUARIO = 10
AND NOT 
    (ID_EMPRESA = 1
    AND ID_USUARIO = 1
    AND ID_MODULO IN (1,2,6))
```

Comment: Where is ID_UNIDADE coming from? That is part of the where clause.

Comment: ID_UNIDADE is under the condition with NOT because is the same table

Comment: @acca90: Please post some data sample