# mysql merge 2 tables,same structure, overlapping values in keys (auto_increment)

Tags: mysql, merge, auto-increment

I have two tables, with the same structure, order_old and order_new. Key field on both is order_id which is auto_increment. order_old has 590 records in it, order_new has 100; I want to copy/add all the data from order_new into order_old, starting after the last record, but am not sure how to do this as the ordr_id keys in order_new are lower than those in order_old

any advise would be appreciated!

David

Answer (score 2):

If no other tables are related to the two, you can use:

```
INSERT INTO order_old
    ( field2          --- do not include the order_id
    , field3
    , ...
    )
SELECT
      field2         --- same here
    , fields3
    , ...
FROM order_new
```

For other options, check this similar question: **[how-can-i-merge-two-mysql-tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725556/how-can-i-merge-two-mysql-tables)**