# php/mysql better option in updating very huge tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have two huge tables. I want to update all fields in the second table with the first if productid and userid matches or insert new if not exist. Will a JOIN be better than a simple UPDATE? What about REPLACE INTO? Can someone help me with the best optimal decision? because the tables are huge.

Thanks.

Comment: lots of data records (about 100billion) and many users performing the same function at a time.

Comment: Hey, This may not be the best solution, but i would use 2 queries for this, the first to update all fields if exist, and then the second to insert where not exist.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725556/how-can-i-merge-two-mysql-tables

Comment: I think a big question here is wether you can stop the db while doing the update or not. Since you may also use php it may be an idea to use a limit clause in the sql and let php do a number of records at a time to avoid total lock on the db until it is finished processing.

Comment: I'd use Joshua's solution, but with a subquery so everything would be done at the SQL, so no need to "stop" the db. Not sure how to do this query, though.

Answer (score 1):

100 billion is pretty rare so I assume you won't find a reliable answer on stackoverflow.

You should do your own benchmarks, look at the [EXPLAIN keyword on mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html) and write a short script [(php one here)](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/count-script-excecution-time/) to analyze the time spent.

On a parallel note, I'm not sure whether MySQL is the best choice for a 100 billion database.