# I want to merge two tables into one whith phpmyadmin

Tags: merge, phpmyadmin

I want to merge two tables into one table.

The first table is images and the columns are;
id, item, name, path, category, sub_category, designer

The second table is items and the columns are:
item, description material, size, color, description

Comment: Duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725556/how-can-i-merge-two-mysql-tables

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

From the website:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_temp2 (fld_id)
  SELECT tbl_temp1.fld_order_id
  FROM tbl_temp1 WHERE tbl_temp1.fld_order_id > 100;
```