# Counting and grouping same named column in different tables (mysql)

Tags: mysql

Okay I have two tables:
Table 1 looks like this:

```
id age gender
1   10   M
2   11   F
3   11   F
```

And Table 2 looks like this (same with different values):

```
id age gender
1  11   F
2  12   M
3  10   M
```

Now I want my final output to look like the following:

```
age count
10   2
11   3
12   1
```

What is the most efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: DO you want to know 'the most efficient way', or just 'a way'?

Comment: Merge the tables via one of the methods in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725556/how-can-i-merge-two-mysql-tables and then do a GROUP BY age

Comment: @Strawberry sorry for replying late, 'a way' and 'the most efficient way' :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to aggregate the union:

```
select age, count(*)
from (select id, age, gender from table1 union all
      select id, age, gender from table2
     ) t
group by age
```

Comment: hey thanks for your answer, works like a charm... if you have some time could you please check this out too? :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14641572/counting-and-grouping-same-named-column-in-different-tables-where-clause-from-o

Comment: @user1768337 . . . Whether you do the union/aggregation (as done here) or aggregation/union/aggregation is really a question of performance.  For large data sets, I might be tempted to do the latter.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select age ,count(age) count from table1 group by age
union
select age, count(age)  count from table2 group by age
```