# Counting and grouping same named column in different tables (where clause from only one table)

Tags: mysql

Okay my question is similar to [Counting and grouping same named column in different tables (mysql)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14635948/counting-and-grouping-same-named-column-in-different-tables-mysql/) but since it might help people looking for exact solution on the internet (like me) I am separating the two questions.

So my table looks similar to that in the link above, with some new columns
Table 1:

```
id age gender published
1   10  M       1
2   11  F       1
3   11  F       0
```

Table 2:

```
id table1id age gender
1    2       11   F
2    2       12   M
3    3       12   M
```

I want to count and group rows from both tables where published = 1. For the second table it should check the published value from the row given by table1id in Table 1. Table1id is the id of the row in Table 1 denoting that table 2 is a subset of table 1. So the result should look something like the following:

```
age count
10  1
11  2
12  1
```

Notice that third row from table 1 is not counted because published is 0. And third row from table 2 is not counted because table1id = 3, which means it's a subset of the 3rd row of table 1 (which has published = 0)

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT age, COUNT(age) cnt
FROM
(
    SELECT
        T2.age 
    FROM Table1 T1
        JOIN Table2 T2
            ON T1.Id = T2.table1id
    WHERE T1.published = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT age
    FROM Table1
    WHERE published = 1
) A
GROUP BY age
```

Comment: wow, you're quick... thanks a ton... it works! I'll set this as the correct answer once I understand what's happening okay? XD edit: okay got it, thanks for help :)