# How to migrate data to one table to another in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv, data-migration

I've two same tables(same table columns and primary key) in two different databases. I want to add 2nd table data to the first table that not exist in the first table (according to the primary key). 
what is the best method to do that?

I can export 2nd table data as `csv`, `php array` or `sql` file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to do this.

The simplest is probably this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/725595/89825):

> ```
> INSERT IGNORE
>   INTO table_1 
> SELECT *
>   FROM table_2
>      ;
> ```
>
> which allows those rows in table_1 to supersede those in table_2 that
>   have a matching primary key, while still inserting rows with new
>   primary keys.

Alternatively, you can use a subquery to find out the rows that are not shared by both tables and insert them. If you've got a *lot* of records, you may want to consider using a temporary table to speed up the process.

Comment: yes. I may have considerable amounts of rows. temporary table for identify not shared rows? is this method can apply for tables in two different databases ?

Comment: I'd say it depends of your permissions. If your user has access to both databases, you should be able to do it. If not, just export one table and import it to the desired database. In any case, backup your data and try the insert ignore method first, you may not need to do use temporary tables at all.

Comment: seems query is not working. Actually I have two databases in WAMP local host. I want to migrate data from one table to another. `insert` table is one databases.  `from` table is one DB. both have same fields.

Comment: Did you try adding the database name before the name of the table? For example: INSERT (...) INTO database1.table_1;