# Merge related data in same row

Tags: mysql

I have a table structured this way:

```
BUSINESS NAME        CATEGORY 
ABC Inc.             Pipes 
ABC Inc.             Plumbing 
Joe's Plumbing       Plumbing 
Joe's Plumbing       Emergency
```

I want to regroup categories in the same row, separated by a character: 
I would then get:

```
ABC Inc.              Pipes,Plumbing 
Joe's Plumbing        Plumbing,Emergency
```

How do I do this ?

Thanks !

Comment: is there any key or foreign key to join?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725556/how-can-i-merge-two-mysql-tables have you tried anything from here?

Answer (score 0):

i cant get proper table name and its fields but you should try like below:

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(BUSINESS NAME) as "Business Name",CATEGORY from table_name group by CATEGORY;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`group_concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function for this.

Make sure you have  `group_concat_max_len` set properly for large data-set in the `group_concat`

```
select
group_concat(distinct business_name order by business_name) as business_name,
category 
from your_table
group by category;
```