# How to MERGE tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, merge

I am trying to merge two tables (studenttarget and studentsource). However, when I execute the following SQL in MySQL Workbench, I receive the error **"''Merge' (merge) is not valid input at this position."** This video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5dk33HN8BX8) got this code to work in SQL Server (@ 7:02 mark) whereas I am using MySQL. Could this be the issue? Is there a better way to go about this? Thanks in advance!

[End Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmpuP.png)

```
MERGE test.studenttarget AS T

USING test.studentsource as S

ON T.ID = S.ID

WHEN MATCHED THEN

    UPDATE SET T.Name = S.Name

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN

    INSERT (ID, Name) Values (S.ID, S.Name)
```

Comment: Yes it is the issue. `Mysql` does not support `Merge` statement

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725556/how-can-i-merge-two-mysql-tables