# Check whether the data exists in MYSQL data base using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, csv, sqlalchemy

I want to write data from an csv file. Everything works fine. If I run my script again I receive an error message:

> IntegrityError: (mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError) 1062 (23000):
>   Duplicate entry 'AAPL' for key 'PRIMARY'

It is due to the fact that the entries are duplicate. How can I check now whether the data which I want to write into the database already exists and process it it exists? The csv file header looks like this

> ticker    isin    product_name    currency    market_data_source  trading_location    country sector

and the data inside like this:

> AAPL  IE00B4BNMY34    Accenture plc   USD Yahoo   NYSE    USA Computer Hardware

And the code like this:

```
import sqlalchemy as sqlal
import pandas as pd

#csv loader
csv_loader = pd.read_csv('C:/Test.csv', encoding='cp1252', sep=';', index_col=0).dropna()

#connection to mysql database
mysql_engine = sqlal.create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://xxx/financialanalysis')
mysql_engine.raw_connection()

metadata = sqlal.MetaData()

#------------------------------
#create table in mysql database
#------------------------------
product  = sqlal.Table('product', metadata,
                       sqlal.Column('ticker', sqlal.String(10), primary_key=True, nullable=False, unique=True),                   
                       sqlal.Column('isin', sqlal.String(12), nullable=True),
                       sqlal.Column('product_name', sqlal.String(80), nullable=True),
                       sqlal.Column('currency', sqlal.String(3), nullable=True),
                       sqlal.Column('market_data_source', sqlal.String(20), nullable=True),
                       sqlal.Column('trading_location', sqlal.String(20), nullable=True),
                       sqlal.Column('country', sqlal.String(20), nullable=True),
                       sqlal.Column('sector', sqlal.String(80), nullable=True),
                       )

metadata.create_all(mysql_engine) 

#Write the data into the mysql database
csv_loader = csv_loader.reset_index()
insert_product_data = product.insert().values(csv_loader.to_dict('records'))
mysql_engine.execute(insert_product_data)
```

Comment: Have you considered using an SQL Merge statement instead of an Insert? That will avoid having to pull all the existing keys from the database into your Python program and check them. It will also allow you to update rows in case new data is present.

Comment: @CJC, do you have an example?

Comment: @CJC no MERGE in mysql

Comment: just use LOAD DATA INFILE.

Comment: @e4c5, do you have an example how it should work when the same data already exists and if the values in the csv file got updates?

Comment: Just google for LOAD DATA INFILE first result

Comment: Apologies, there's no natural merge statement, but try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725556/how-can-i-merge-two-mysql-tables

Comment: @e4c5, I solved it by using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`. The main question is how to update existing values using this statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it by using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`