# how to select data from a table useing values from another table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to select data from a table called `tbl_users` using a value from another table called `mergeing` and column called `donator_1`.

I tried the following:

```php
$result = $DBcon->query("SELECT tbl_users.username, tbl_users.email, tbl_users.Phone_number FROM tbl_users,mergeing WHERE mergeing.donator_1= tbl_users.user_id AND mergeing._id = 6");
while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
  echo '<b>' . $l['user_id'] .'</b><b>' . $l['username'] . '</b>';
}
```

Comment: check out this link, this might help you find the answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725556/how-can-i-merge-two-mysql-tables

Comment: Look up inner join, I'm guessing its doesn't like From A, B.. Considered very bad form that.

Comment: Why have you got a second opening php tag i.e. `<?php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try nested queries:

```sql
SELECT username, email, Phone_number
FROM tbl_users
WHERE user_id = (SELECT donator_1 FROM mergeing WHERE _id = 6 )
```

or an inner join :

```sql
SELECT username, email, Phone_number
FROM tbl_users
JOIN mergeing ON tbl_users.user_id = mergeing.donator_1
WHERE mergeing._id = 6
```

Comment: thanks the first one didn't work but the second one did